# Good practice to check if std:array of unsigned char is initialized

Tags: c++, stl

I need to check if std:array was initialized (or some default common value).
The array is optional , so i need to check if it has value or not.
I dont use boost.
i tried this:

```
array<unsigned char, 2> testArr;
testArr.fill(0);
if(testArr.empty()){
    cout << "testArr is empty" <<endl ;
}
```

i am lookin for a simple way to init to default value and check if default value without iterate (by myself) , is there something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no ways to do this without optional or something else, since `std::array::empty()`

**Checks if the container has no elements, i.e. whether begin() == end().**

So, checks, that there is no elements in container (i.e. `std::array<T, 0>`) and nothing else. You should use any optional class, or iterate over array and check values. If you don't want use `boost::optional` - write your own optional like `boost::optional`. It's very simple.

Comment: So  why array has empty() method? its not a dynamic array it will always be with some size.

Comment: @user149518 since array with size 0 is special-case. And array is container, so it should meet container requeirements where a.empty() convertible to
bool
a.begin() ==
a.end()
constant

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Just don't leave it uninitialized. Consider something like `boost::optional<array<unsigned char, 2>>` if it doesn't always carry useful data.

Comment: i need some default value and to check if its the default value.

Comment: @user1495181 that's the motivation for boost::optional. `boost::none` is the default value, and converting it to bool is check if it's the default value.

Comment: I dont use boost.the optional is exactly the case here, but i will not add boost only for this (few classed)

Comment: @user1495181 Use the [Boost bcp](http://www.boost.org/doc/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html) tool to extract only the headers required for `optional` then.

Comment: Or you could consider that most people who avoid Boost say that about several things. They deny the use of each component because it on its own is not enough to justify it in their mind. But when you say that 10 times...